# How to connect Azure AD with PowerApps forms

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, powerapps

I am creating a Leave Request form on PowerApps and i want to connect it with Azure AD of my organization.
The scenario is:
 1. User fills up the form of Leave Request
 2. The "Employee Name" and "Department" fields should be called by itself in the text box. I want to call these identities from Azure AD.

How can i perform this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not available to connect to Azure AD to get the data in the PowerApps.

However it is able to get the user information using the `User().FullName` function to get the current username. If you also want it support to retrieve the department of current user, you may submit the feedback from [here](https://powerapps.uservoice.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There is a system called Microsoft Flows where you can interface between Azure AD and your PowerApps application. I've been using it and albeit the fact that it's new and a little buggy, it's a possible solution for your problem.